# suggestions for a developement studio solution (source repo + bug tracker + build management)

Tags: svn, build-automation, development-environment, bug-tracking

we are a team of 10 looking to develop our next APP.

Need a quick solution for managing source code repo + defect tracker + build management.

Altassian JIRA studio looks complelling but it is a hosted solution,we are not okay to have our source code on a cloud !

are there any options? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collabnet's Teamforge perhaps, svn integration (obviously), bug tracker, Hudson for CI, plugins for various IDEs, and some other bits n bobs like agile task trackery features.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse, with Subclipse plugin takes care of IDE and source code version control. It also has Maven plugin to do builds and release management. I use bugzilla for bug tracking which I dont think is integrated with Eclipse but there are other tools that will help you get there, look at eclipse projects plugin repository [here](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/).